Just some problems dynamic links
basicily im having problems with making the link to comments dynamic. my goal is that no matter what number i put in it the get will enter my call and give me the id i want the call looks like http://localhost:1234/comments?id=num but im not finding anything that can let my call be dynamic any help is grateful
server.js
    
    (async () => {
        const db = require("./database");
        const users = await db.selectUsers();
        console.log(users);
        /*const assoc = await db.selectAssoc();
        console.log(assoc);*/
        const processRequest = require('./processRequest');
        const aplicacao = processRequest(1234);
        aplicacao.get('/users',function(req,res){
            res.write(JSON.stringify(users));
            res.end();
        });
        aplicacao.get('/comments?id=1',function(req,res){
            console.log("entered");
            res.end();
        });
    })();    

processRequest.js

   var http = require('http'); 
var criarProcessRequest = function(porta){
    var entrada = {};// Api de entrada
    var caminhos = {};// rotas para o pedido
    var metodos = ['GET','POST'];// O pedido é enviado com maisculas    
    metodos.forEach(function(metodo){
        caminhos[metodo] = {};
        entrada[metodo.toLowerCase()] = function(path,fn){
            caminhos[metodo][path] = fn;
        };
    });
    http.createServer(function(req,res){
        res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin','*');
        if(!caminhos[req.method][req.url]){
            res.statusCode = 404;
            return res.end();
        }
        caminhos[req.method][req.url](req,res);
    }).listen(porta);
    return entrada;
};
module.exports = criarProcessRequest;


also sorry if the english is bad it isnt my first languege
i have tried special characters like #,$,&,? and have tried researching

An easy and popular approach is to use Express on your server side.  Geeks for Geeks has a concise example with query params here https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/reading-query-parameters-in-node-js/

If you're using vanilla Node.js, you can utilize the built-in url module to parse the URL:
const url = require('url');

aplicacao.get('/comments', function(req, res) {
  const parsedUrl = url.parse(req.url, true);
  const id = parsedUrl.query.id;

  ...
});

Using the Express.js framework makes it easier, as you can access URL parameters directly using req.query.

thank you very much for the response i will try it tommorow
